# A list of a list?

Tags: linked-list, ada, multidimensional-array

Trying to make a custom data type involving lists, and it seems to be fine accepting most generic types
I don't know how to make a list of lists though, it seems...

In my main procedure I was hoping to get away with something like this:

```
type INFO is record
   Neighbors:List(ITEM => Unbounded_String);
   Name:Unbounded_String;
end record;
package Graph is new List(ITEM => INFO);
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 4):

Well, for your Neighbors field you have to specify a type. The incorrect syntax that's there is reminiscent of a generic instantiation.

Something more along the lines of this (warning, not compiled):

```
package List_Of_Strings is new List(Item => Unbounded_String);

type INFO is record
   Neighbors:List_Of_Strings.List_Type;
   Name:Unbounded_String;
end record;
package Graph is new List(ITEM => INFO);
```

Then Graph.List_Type will be your list of Info records.

Caution, though! You have to keep a clear understanding of pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference semantics when updating list items.